# Oracle - How to check my date field value has time portion or not

Tags: oracle, date, datetime, time, plsql

I have a table containing a date type field and it holds few records with date value with time portion and few records only have date value without time portion. How to check which record has time portion and what not without navigating record by record?

This is what I'm using at the moment, but I want something faster:

```
SELECT MY_TAB.SEQ, MY_TAB.CRTE_DT,
       CASE WHEN TRUNC (MY_TAB.CRTE_DT) = MY_TAB.CRTE_DT
       THEN 'False' ELSE 'True' END AS "Has Time Portion"
FROM (SELECT 1 AS SEQ,
             TO_DATE ('7/28/2013', 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS CRTE_DT
      FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 2 AS SEQ,
             TO_DATE ('11/07/2013 12:27:54', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS CRTE_DT
      FROM DUAL) MY_TAB;
```

Comment: I am submitting one solution to my own problem but looking forward more optimized solutions if anyone knows.


SELECT MY_TAB.SEQ, MY_TAB.CRTE_DT,
       CASE
          WHEN TRUNC (MY_TAB.CRTE_DT) = MY_TAB.CRTE_DT THEN 'False'
          ELSE 'True'
       END
          AS "Has Time Portion"
  FROM (SELECT 1 AS SEQ, TO_DATE ('7/28/2013', 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS CRTE_DT FROM DUAL
        UNION
        SELECT 2 AS SEQ, TO_DATE ('11/07/2013 12:27:54', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS CRTE_DT FROM DUAL) MY_TAB;

Comment: ALL dates in Oracle have a time portion. For example, `TO_DATE('7/28/2013','MM/DD/YYYY')` has a time portion of 12:00am (midnight).

Answer (score 1):

Nice Solution. Just one catch. If the timestamp is of 12:00 am midnight, then the result will be false.

TO_DATE ('11/07/2013 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') will yield to  false

Comment: For me Oracle stored only date portion when I tried to insert a date with 00:00:00 time portion.

Answer (score 1):

CREATE TABLE MY_TAB
AS
   SELECT SEQ, CRTE_DT
     FROM (SELECT 1 AS SEQ, TO_DATE ('7/28/2013', 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS CRTE_DT FROM DUAL
           UNION
           SELECT 2 AS SEQ,
                  TO_DATE ('11/07/2013 12:27:54', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS CRTE_DT FROM DUAL
           UNION
           SELECT 3 AS SEQ,
                  TO_DATE ('09/5/2013 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS CRTE_DT FROM DUAL
           UNION
           SELECT 4 AS SEQ, TO_DATE ('4/15/2013 00:00:01', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS CRTE_DT FROM DUAL
           UNION
           SELECT 5 AS SEQ, TO_DATE ('12/12/2012 1:01:01', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS CRTE_DT FROM DUAL);

SELECT MY_TAB.SEQ, MY_TAB.CRTE_DT,
       CASE WHEN TRUNC (MY_TAB.CRTE_DT) = MY_TAB.CRTE_DT
       THEN 'False' ELSE 'True' END AS "Has Time Portion"
  FROM MY_TAB;

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check the data field contains time portion or not, you can do it by altering the session as,

```
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'dd/mm/yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> SELECT SYSDATE FROM dual;

SYSDATE
----------
08/11/2013

SQL> ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> SELECT SYSDATE FROM dual;

SYSDATE
-------------------
08/11/2013 08:30:49
```

Comment: Thanks. What you showed is new to me but I actually wanted to pull both types of date values from single table within same session.