# Find timestamp in dates

Tags: oracle, date, time

i have table (sample below),

ARTICLE DATE

```
104425  05.09.2014
105996  24.07.2014
105999  13.07.2014 3:00:00
106005  14.08.2014
106008  05.07.2014
```

how can i select rows with time in it?

UPD: Colomn DATE have (DD.MM.YYYY) and (DD.MM.YYYY H24:MI:SS) simultaneously

Comment: has field `DATE` type `date` ?

Comment: yea. just checked name:DATE data type: DATE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please, try

```
select * from your_table where trunc(date) != date
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand clearly what you want. Does your table have a Time column ? In that case you should do something like :

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE Time IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Colomn DATE have (DD.MM.YYYY) and (DD.MM.YYYY H24:MI:SS) simultaneously

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19850007/oracle-how-to-check-my-date-field-value-has-time-portion-or-not

Answer (score 0):

The Oracle `date` datatype always has a time component. The way the date is being displayed on your system causes the time to be omitted if it's midnight. In order to get this to do what you want, you need to exclude those times that are at midnight. `trunc` can be used to set a `date` to midnight, which is why `select * from your_table where trunc(date) <> date` works. However, you should be aware that this could cause unexpected side effects if you ever intentionally set the time to midnight.